# L&H_Reader news reader? What's this?

Tags: nntp, usenet

A message source shows

User-Agent: L&H_Reader

What news reader is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Lernout & Hauspie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernout_&_Hauspie) is a producer of speech synthesis software. I can't find any product named "Reader" on their website, but I am guessing this is a screen reader of some sort that reads the contents of web pages aloud.

Comment: Are you certain L&H_Reader refers to one of their readers or is this just a guess?

Comment: It's a very educated guess :) if we were betting, I'd risk a bottle of good red wine, I'm quite sure it's Lernout & Hauspie here. There seems to be nothing on Google, you could ask them.